# Salesforce Email replies to GMail with Chinese Characters

Tags: community

I got an email from "user@example.com"  with the Chinese character to Salesforce as inbound message and i replied with Chinese characters from Salesforce to this user@example.com without any issue.

But user@example.com was received in gmail inbox and he opened the email to read but its showing all the Chinese characters as converted to ???????????? questions marks.

He is not able to read the Chinese character content which I replied to his email back.

Please help me what might be the issue is there any issue from Salesforce end or Gmail?

Comment: How are you replying back to the e-mails? Is it an e-mail template? Additionally, what font are you using?

Comment: Okey, i have configured email-to-Case, once the email to come to salesforce normally we use to reply to the particular customer.i used the font as English only. but the original contact of chinese characters was changed to ????? in his gmail box when he got reply from salesforce

Comment: You can use the Arial Unicode MS font to handle chinese characters.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a font issue. Common fonts such as, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif aren't Chinese fonts. Those characters aren't included in that package.

If using Chinese fonts is important, it may be worth checking out [this guide](http://www.kendraschaefer.com/2012/06/chinese-standard-web-fonts-the-ultimate-guide-to-css-font-family-declarations-for-web-design-in-simplified-chinese/) here. But the long and short of it is, you need to use a Chinese fonts. Below are some examples taken from that link:

**Windows**

> 黑体：SimHei
>
> 宋体：SimSun
>
> 新宋体：NSimSun

**Mac**

> 华文细黑：STHeiti Light
>
> 华文黑体：STHeiti
>
> 冬青黑体: Hiragino Sans GB

Google and Adobe also offer web fonts if you'd rather serve your fonts via a CDN:

**Google**

> noto-sans-hans

**Adobe**

> source-han-sans

This isn't an exhaustive list of fonts, but using these should get you moving with delivering e-mail in Chinese properly.

Comment: Oh! No Dan, i tried to send an email from salesforce using chinese character to other domain like gmail, outlook, but no luck chinese content is showing as like ?????????? into their gmail and outlook. some thing wrong i will raise salesforce ticket. this is something strange.

Comment: @Sathish I understand that, but what font is the e-mail you're sending using? I suspect that font doesn't support Chinese characters.

Answer (score 0):

If using email templates, check the encoding and be sure it is UTF-8. Your default might be ISO 8859-1

[image]

If using Apex outbound email, verify you are using [this method call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm%23apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_setCharset?search_text=email%20methods):

```
setCharset('UTF-8');  // default is running user's charset
```